# Ruby on Rails WashOut GEM SOAP Defining events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, wash-out

I have this code:

```
soap_action "relatorio",
           :args => {:a => :integer},
               :return => :string,
           :response_tag => "Relatorios"

  def relatorio
  @relato = Relato.where(cliente_id: params[:a]).pluck(:projeto_id)
  @relati = Relato.where(cliente_id: params[:a])
  @reltask = Reltask.where(relato_id: @relati).pluck(:task_id)
  render :soap => :relato => {@relato}, :reltask => {@reltask}
       end
```

Which is wrong in the render, this is what i need, i need to xml respond like
 DATA 
 DATA

how to make it right, i'm trying different ways but i couldn't figure it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code should look like

```
soap_action "relato",
:args => {:a => :integer},
:return => {
:relato => [{:projeto => :string, :atividade => :string}]
}
def relato
@relato = Relato.where(cliente_id: params[:a]).pluck(:projeto_id)
  @relati = Relato.where(cliente_id: params[:a])
  @reltask = Reltask.where(relato_id: @relati).pluck(:task_id)
render :soap =>
{:relato => [
{:projeto => @relato, :atividade => @reltask }]}
end
```